# What do they mean by using asterisks in this "Public Suffix List" of TLDs?

Tags: top-level-domains

This list of domains: https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

> The wildcard character * (asterisk) matches any valid sequence of
>   characters in a hostname part. (Note: the list uses Unicode, not
>   Punycode forms, and is encoded using UTF-8.) Wildcards are not
>   restricted to appear only in the leftmost position, but they must
>   wildcard an entire label. (I.e. *.*.foo is a valid rule: *bar.foo is
>   not.)

Source: https://publicsuffix.org/list/

I've read the above and that whole page several times by now and don't understand it. I understand that the "!" entries mean "exceptions", but I don't get what the ones beginning with "*." mean, since that seems to be implied for all of them. After they, they are a list of "in practice" TLDs.

Their description only further confuses me. I don't understand what makes those entries different from all the of other ones.

Comment: To potentially clarify, the wildcard is part of the suffix. Ie, the registerable names are one level further down, under any number of not enumerated subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

That list is a list of domains that should not have cookies because domains can be registered under them.  For that purpose, there is a difference between `example.com` and `*.example.com` on that list.

When `example.com` is on the list, it means that cookies should NOT be allowed at `example.com` but SHOULD be allowed for `sub.example.com`,  `sub.sub.example.com`, `another.example.com` and `sub.another.example.com`.

When `*.example.com` is on the list, it means that cookies should NOT be allowed at `example.com`, `sub.example.com`, or `another.example.com` but SHOULD be allowed for `sub.sub.example.com` and `sub.another.example.com`.

This is to account for when registration of sub-sub-domains is allowed but not the registration of sub-domains.